# Curl and utf-8 for push notification

Tags: php, curl, utf-8

I have a PHP script aimed at sending push notifications to a mobile app.
The title is properly sent in utf-8 and when I test utf-8 strings (such has "accepté") it appears properly on the mobile. But, for any reason, this doesn't work with the message part.
The part of the code sending the message is as follow:

```
$data = array(
    'Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8',
    'registration_id' => $deviceToken,
    'collapse_key' => $collapseKey,
    'data.message' => $messageText,
    'data.title' => 'my title');

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $this->ssl);
if($headers)
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "UTF-8");

$response = curl_exec($ch);
$httpCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

curl_close($ch);
```

I used echo to print the message just before $ch = curl_init(), and $data['data.message'] output properly the message. I have tried several solutions: iconv, mb_convert_encoding, utf8_encode,...None worked. What I really don't understand is, why this issue occur with the message and not the title?

EDIT: 
I eventually figured how to fix it: the message is from a sql database, I just needed to add:

```
$query = "SET NAMES UTF8";
mysqli_query($db, $query);
```

just after $db = mysqli_connect().

Comment: Does the message part come from the database? If so, make sure the field is UTF-8 encoded. And the title, does it come from the same place as the message? Also, when you say you tried iconv and etc and it didn't work, what was the result? (returns empty string, accentuated characters simply disapeared, nothing changed)

Answer (score 0):

I eventually figured how to fix it: the message is from a sql database, I just needed to add:

```
$query = "SET NAMES UTF8";
mysqli_query($db, $query);
```

just after $db = mysqli_connect().